# Trouble negating `is_a?` in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class C
   attr_accessor :v
   def initialize(arg)
     @v = arg
   end
   def meth(arg=nil)
     return arg.meth unless (arg.nil?) && !(arg.is_a? self.class)
     @v
   end
end
```

In `meth` I want to do `arg.meth` if arg is not nil and if `arg.is_a?C`. Otherwise return `@v`.  But I guess this part `!(arg.is_a? self.class)` is incorrect. Couldn't figure out whats wrong.

```
x = C.new("first")
y = C.new("second")

x.meth #=> "first"
x.meth(y) #=> "second"
x.meth(10) #=> I was expecting 'first'

But I get NoMethodError: undefined method `meth' for 10:Fixnum
```

I do not want to negate `arg.nil?` I would like to achieve `arg.is_not_a?`

Update: Looks like my question is confusing. I am trying to clarify here

```
if the argument passed to meth is not nil and is of type C then 
  call arg.meth 
else 
  return @v
end
```

Comment: I tried `!(arg.is_a? self.class)` in the console and it works.  I specifically tried `!(nil.is_a? nil.class)`.

Comment: Not clear what you want.. could you tell me the logic you are trying to build..? what is this for `!(arg.is_a? self.class)` ?

Comment: isn't better to use `instance_of`?

Comment: @Andrea You are right!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`10.nil?` is false, and thus `(arg.nil?) && !(arg.is_a? self.class)` is false, and given how `unless` works, your method is going to try to call `10.meth`.

Replace that line with either:

```
return arg.meth if !arg.nil? && (arg.is_a? self.class)
```

or

```
return arg.meth unless arg.nil? || !(arg.is_a? self.class)
```

EDIT: since `arg.is_a? self.class` implies `!arg.nil?` the above is redundant, and should really just be:

```
return arg.meth if arg.is_a? self.class
```

or, if you really really want to use unless:

```
return arg.meth unless !(arg.is_a? self.class)
```

The explicit return isn't idiomatic Ruby, so something like this would probably be ideal

```
def meth(arg=nil)
  arg.is_a?(self.class) ? arg.meth : @v
end
```

Comment: I think you changed the `and` logic to `or`... Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

The condition `(arg.nil?) && !(arg.is_a? self.class)` will be true if `arg` is `nil` **and** `arg` is not (sub)instance of `self.class`. You are using this condition in `unless`, so everything is reversed: "`arg` is `nil`" turns into "`arg` is not `nil`", "`arg` is not (sub)instance of `self.class`" turns into "`arg` is (sub)instance of `self.class`", and most importantly - "and" turns into "or" - and that's your problem: `arg.meth` is called if either `arg` is not `nil` **or** `arg` is (sub)instance of `self.class` - but you only want it to happen if **both** conditions yield true.

So - either change `&&` to `||`, or change `unless` to `if`(and rewrite the condition accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

As you said - ***In `meth` I want to do `arg.meth` if arg is not `nil` and if `arg.is_a C`.Otherwise return `@v`.***

This can be handled in doing simple calling the method `#instance_of?` on `arg`. You don't need to check explicitly the `nil` object. The `if` statement will be evaluated as `true`,only when `arg` is an instance of class `C`.Neither `nil`,nor `10` is an instance of your class `C`,so `arg.meth` wouldn't happen as the `if` clause will be evaluated as `false`. Which actually satisfies your need.`arg.meth` would happen in the `if` clause,when `arg` will be the instance of class `c`. And this is the case happened in this line `x.meth(y)`.

Here is the code you are trying to get :

```
class C
   attr_accessor :v
   def initialize(arg)
     @v = arg
   end
   def meth(arg=nil)
     return arg.meth if arg.instance_of?(self.class)
     @v
   end
end 

x = C.new("first")
y = C.new("second")

x.meth # => "first"
x.meth(y) # => "second"
x.meth(10) # => "first"
```

Comment: Please could you modify it with `unless`